# Combine multiple maps in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have three maps, one list give me a map of sold cars in the last year, the second map give a list of sold cars in six month
and the third map give me a list of sold cars in the last month. see below

```
totalYear = [
    [brand:"BMW"],
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"mercedes"], 
    [brand:"mercedes"], 
    [brand:"mercedes"]
]

totalSixMonth = [
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"BMW"],
    [brand:"BMW"],
    [brand:"mercedes"], 
    [brand:"mercedes"] 
]

totalMonth = [
    [brand:"BMW"], 
    [brand:"mercedes"]                      
]
```

How can I combine this maps into one map like

```
total = [
    [totalMonth:"1", totalSixMonth:"3", totalYear:"7", brand:"BMW"], 
    [totalMonth:"1", totalSixMonth:"2", totalYear:"3", brand:"mercedes"] 
]
```

I tried `groupBy` and `collect` but they are not giving the right result. Who can help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// Something to extract counts
def counts = { input -> input.groupBy { it.brand }.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.size()] } }

def result = [totalYear:totalYear, totalSixMonth:totalSixMonth, totalMonth:totalMonth]
    .collectMany { name, list -> // (A)
        counts(list).collect { brand, num -> [(name):num, brand:brand] }
    }
    .groupBy { it.brand } // (B)
    .collect { it.value } // (C)
    .collect {
        it.inject { a, b -> a + b } // (D)
    }
```

To give the result:

```
[
    ['totalYear':7, 'brand':'BMW', 'totalSixMonth':3, 'totalMonth':1],
    ['totalYear':3, 'brand':'mercedes', 'totalSixMonth':2, 'totalMonth':1]
]
```

---

To explain a bit, here's what the data looks like at each stage:

After the collectMany at (A), we have data in the form:

```
[['totalYear':7, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalYear':3, 'brand':'mercedes'], ['totalSixMonth':3, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalSixMonth':2, 'brand':'mercedes'], ['totalMonth':1, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalMonth':1, 'brand':'mercedes']]
```

After the `groupBy` at (B), this becomes:

```
['BMW':[['totalYear':7, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalSixMonth':3, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalMonth':1, 'brand':'BMW']], 'mercedes':[['totalYear':3, 'brand':'mercedes'], ['totalSixMonth':2, 'brand':'mercedes'], ['totalMonth':1, 'brand':'mercedes']]]
```

We can then throw away the keys of this map at (C), to get a list of lists of maps:

```
[[['totalYear':7, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalSixMonth':3, 'brand':'BMW'], ['totalMonth':1, 'brand':'BMW']], [['totalYear':3, 'brand':'mercedes'], ['totalSixMonth':2, 'brand':'mercedes'], ['totalMonth':1, 'brand':'mercedes']]]
```

For each of these lists of maps, we can then use `inject` to collapse them into a single map at (D), so we end up with just a list of maps, and our final result.

There's probably a shorter way to the same result, as this feels like it does too many groupBy calls...

---

An alternative, but not much shorter (if at all)

```
def result = [totalYear:totalYear, totalSixMonth:totalSixMonth, totalMonth:totalMonth]
    .collectMany { name, list ->
        list.countBy { it.brand }.collect { brand, count ->
            [(name): count, brand: brand]
        }
    }
    .groupBy { it.brand }.values()*.inject { a, b -> a + b }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can do is combine the three `Map`s into one, with each variable being the key and the `Map` the value. After that, you'll need a series of transformations.

```
def total = [totalYear: totalYear, totalSixMonth: totalSixMonth, totalMonth: totalMonth].collectEntries { label, maps ->
    [(label): maps.countBy { it.brand} ]
}.inject([:]) { result, label, counts -> 
    counts.entrySet().each { entry -> 
        if(!result[entry.key]) result[entry.key] = [:]
        result[entry.key][(label)] = entry.value
    }
    result
}.collect { brand, counts -> [brand: brand] << counts }
```

The `collectEntries()` accumulates the totals:

```
[totalYear:[BMW:7, mercedes:3], totalSixMonth:[BMW:3, mercedes:2], totalMonth:[BMW:1, mercedes:1]]
```

The `inject()` groups the totals by brand:

```
[BMW:[totalYear:7, totalSixMonth:3, totalMonth:1], mercedes:[totalYear:3, totalSixMonth:2, totalMonth:1]]
```

Finally, the `collect()` builds the final list:

```
[['brand':'BMW', 'totalYear':7, 'totalSixMonth':3, 'totalMonth':1], ['brand':'mercedes', 'totalYear':3, 'totalSixMonth':2, 'totalMonth':1]]
```

*NOTE: You asked for a `Map` but demonstrated a `List` or `Map`s. I went with the demonstration.*

Comment: @Rosa, you are right I made a mistake it is a list. i will modify my question. Can you tell me how to combine the lists in grails?

Comment: You mean combine the three Maps? I see now how I misled you. I combined the Maps in the first line of code in my example. Basically, I created a new Map containing the other three: `[totalYear: totalYear, totalSixMonth: totalSixMonth, totalMonth: totalMonth]`